# Passing a date parameter into a SAS code from table

Tags: sas, sas-macro, 4gl

I have to perform a number of processing for past 2 years (2017-2019) within SAS for every month.

I have a job that uses a YYMMDD parameter to indicate what data should be used from the data warehouse.

Lets say i have a table with JOB_NAME and JOB_DATE columns along with conditions (based on rc value the next one will start or not).

How can i tell SAS to take the date parameter from a certain column in a certain table?

Comment: Not clear what you are talking about.  How are you running SAS?  How are you passing the parameter? Is it a macro variable? Does it have a date value, like `21833` or `"05OCT2019"d`, or just a string of digits like `20191005`? Hopefully you aren't using 2 digits for year.

Comment: You probably want to look into CALL EXECUTE(). Check the documentation for a full example on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just format after loading dataset...

```
data Want;
    set have;
    format JOB_DATE YYMMDD10. /*or use YYMMDD8.*/;
run;
```